# How can I stop my center div from changing position after I SlideUp another divs?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, layout

I'm creating simple page with a `<header>` and a `<section>`. In the `section` I have 3 divs and I am positioning them with `display: flex;` and `justify-content: space-between`.

The problem is that I also use JS `slideToggle()` on two of them (extreme ones). It is changing the layout of my center div after they are going up. How can I do it so that my center div doesn't change position after one of the others is slid up?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#playlist').click(function() {
    $('#nav').slideToggle();
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#songs').click(function() {
    $('#listSongs').slideToggle();

  });
});
```

```css
section {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#listSongs {
  margin-top: 50px;
  height: 550px;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 25px;
  width: 200px;
}

#listSongs p {
  margin-top: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 50px;
  color: white;
}

#player {
  color: red;
}

#nav {
  margin-top: 50px;
  height: 550px;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 20px;
  width: 200px;
}

.hidden {
  margin-top: 50px;
  height: 550px;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

#nav p {
  text-align: center;
}

#nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <div id="listSongs">
    <p>Authors:</p>
    <div class="after"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="player">
    <p>something</p>
  </div>
  <div id="nav">
    <p>something</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because when the `slideUp`/`slideDown`/`slideToggle` methods complete, they set `display: none` on the target element. This is what causes the layout of your page to shift.

To workaround, and improve the animation, you can use CSS instead. Use the `transition` property to animate the `height` setting. Then you can toggle a class which sets `height: 0` on the target element. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#playlist').click(function() {
    $('#nav').toggleClass('hide');
  });

  $('#songs').click(function() {
    $('#listSongs').toggleClass('hide');
  });
});
```

```css
body { background-color: #CCC; }
section {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

section > div.panel {
  margin-top: 50px;
  height: 550px;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 25px;
  width: 200px;
  transition: height 0.4s;
  overflow: hidden;
}

section > div.panel.hide {
  height: 0;
}

section > div.panel p {
  margin-top: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 50px;
  color: white;
}

#player {
  color: red;
}

#nav {
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="playlist">Playlist</button>
<button id="songs">Songs</button>
<section>
  <div id="listSongs" class="panel">
    <p>Authors:</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <div class="after"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="player">
    <p>something</p>
  </div>
  <div id="nav" class="panel">
    <p>something</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Note that I also rearranged some of the CSS to make it more generic with less repetition.